# Magento 2 REST API: Empty cart or delete multiple items from the cart

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api

I am working on a headless magento solution, but I am facing a bit of a problem.

As the official magento 2 docs suggest, cart items can be deleted using these:

> **DELETE**  /V1/guest-carts/:cartId/items/:itemId ->  For Guest Users
>
> **DELETE** /V1/carts/mine/items/:itemId  -> For Signed-in users

Is there a way to delete multiple items without using the same API multiple times, or more conveniently empty the cart?

Answer (score -1):

Magento documentation does not specify an endpoint that allows for bulk deletion. Neither for [signed-in users](https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/customer-rest-api.html) nor [guest users](https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/guest-rest-api.html).

You can, however, define custom endpoints (see an [official documentation page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html#configure-webapi)). There's also a [tutorial](https://www.thirdandgrove.com/insights/creating-custom-rest-api-magento2/) that shows how to do it for bulk edit.